# Sorting algorithm with arrayLists

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, oop, arraylist

I'm trying to make a scheduling program where no two talks can proceed at the same time, although a talk can proceed as the other one ends. After putting the first talk into Scheduler plan, I want to go through each talk in my arrayList and check if there compatible with the last talk in the schedule.

I figure I can check by comparing if the startTime of index i is greater than the endtime of index i-1.

I sorted my talks and lectures by there endTime and inputted the first array. Now I'm having trouble comparing the events and adding the right ones into Scheduler plan.

```
public class Scheduler {

private  ArrayList<Event> events = new ArrayList <Event>();

public Scheduler(ArrayList<Event> events){ //Constructor
    for (int i=0; i<events.size(); i++)
        this.events.add(events.get(i));
    }

    public ArrayList<Event> getsortSchedule(){ //Sorting Algorithm
        int N = events.size() -1;

            for (int i = 0; i <=(N-1); i++)
        {
                for(int j = 1; j <= N;j++)
                {
                        if(events.get(i).getendTime().compareTo(events.get(j).getendTime()) > 0)  
                        Collections.swap(events, i, j);
                }   
        }


        return events;
    }

    public Scheduler getSchedule(){ //Scheduling attempt
        Scheduler plan = new Scheduler(events);
        this.events.add(events.get(0));

        for (int i=0; i == events.size(); i++)
        {
            //if(events.get(i).getStartTime() > events.get(i).getendTime())
            //if(events.get(i).getStartTime().compareTo(events.get(l).getendTime()) > events.get(i-1).getendTime().compareTo(events.get(l).getendTime()))  
            this.events.add(events.get(i));
        }

        return plan;
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by **comparing the events** ? You are already comparing with event `endtime` right (but not using `collection` `sort` method)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **ArrayList** then you can use **Collections** ...

dont reinvent the wheel and sort the list doing

```
Collections.sort(events);
```

Comment: @Xocę But I need to compare the startTime and endTime to make sure no events are going on at the same time before I put them into `Scheduler plan`

Comment: If you allow me a hint: short answers are sometimes fine; but I think you very often dump some half-ready half-nothing answer. I think a bit more of *quality* would help you collecting more upvotes ...